# How to convert a Boost::make_recursive_variant Object into a string?

Tags: java, c++, string, boost, boost-variant

Been playing with Boost:make_recursive_variant and I'm quite stump on how to create a string from a given Variant and return it.

I can output easily using cout, but my goal was to create a C++ Version of Arrays.deeptoString from java to return a string. Kept running into compile issues trying to work around recursive_variant. Here my Current Code for Arrays.deeptoString.

```
typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<string, int, vector<boost::recursive_variant_ > >::type ObjectE;
class deepToString : public boost::static_visitor<std::string> {
public:
    string operator()(const int i) const {
        storedString += i;
        storedString += ",";
        return storedString;
    }
    string operator()(std::vector<ObjectE> const &v) const {
        storedString += "[";
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
            storedString += boost::apply_visitor(create_string(), v[i]);
            storedString += ",";
        }
        storedString += boost::apply_visitor(create_string(), v[v.size() - 1]);
        storedString += "]";
        return storedString;
    }
    string operator()(std::string const &s) const {
        storedString += s;
        storedString += ",";
    }
    mutable string storedString = "";
};
```

I was hoping I could return the string, but instead it just crashes on me. I... both love and hate recursive variants atm. Ideally if there was a given

```
ObjectE t = ["string" , [1, 2] , ["str2", "str3"], [1,3,6], [[1,2], [1,4]]]
```

I should be able to do the following line to get

```
string output = boost::apply_visitor(deepToString(), t);
```

output get

```
 "["string" , [1, 2] , ["str2", "str3"], [1,3,6], [[1,2], [1,4]]]"
```

At the start, I tried not using const methods since we are changing the values inside the method, but I got a large series of compiles errors. This current style compiles for me, but will crash on me. I should have prob look into why it crashing first.

Any ideas on how I should approach this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems:

1. doing `storedString += i;` (where `i` is `int`) doesn't do what you think it does
2. You fail to return a value from `operator()(std::string const&) const`
3. You recurse into `create_string()` which is a temporary; this is the reason you couldn't make things `const` properly

Fixing all that and doing it right with the mutable/const:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71b7c8732fcadc3c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string, int, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> >::type ObjectE;
typedef std::vector<ObjectE> ObjectV;

struct create_string : boost::static_visitor<std::string const&> {
    std::string const& operator()(const int i) {
        return storedString += std::to_string(i) + ", ";
    }
    std::string const& operator()(ObjectV const &v) {
        storedString += "[ ";
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
            create_string nest;
            storedString += boost::apply_visitor(nest, v[i]) + ", ";
        }
        create_string nest;
        storedString += boost::apply_visitor(nest, v[v.size() - 1]);
        return storedString += " ]";
    }
    std::string const& operator()(std::string const &s) {
        return storedString += s + ", ";
    }

    std::string storedString = "";
};

int main() {
    ObjectE obj = ObjectV { 
        1,
        "hello world",
        ObjectV {
            42, ObjectV { "some more" }, -42
        },
    };

    create_string vis;

    std::cout << "Result '" << boost::apply_visitor(vis, obj) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Result '[ 1, , hello world, , [ 42, , [ some more,  ], -42,  ] ]'
```

### Improving

You can do a lot better.

- First you can reduce allocations by using a stream instead of copying strings. This could also be made to make the visitor stateless.
- You can also make the visitor apply directly to variants, so you don't have to invoke `apply_visitor` anymore.
- You can avoid the redundant commas and use `std::quoted` to properly escape the string values (in case they contain `"`, `[`, `]`, `,`)
- You can make everything generic so it works with a lot more variants

Here's the implementation of these bullets:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77d37747d81fff7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<std::string, int, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_> >::type ObjectE;
typedef std::vector<ObjectE> ObjectV;

struct printer {
    using result_type = void;
    std::ostream& _os;

    // forwards for `operator()`
    template <typename T> void call(T const& v) const { return operator()(v); }

    // dispatch for variants
    template <typename... Ts> void operator()(boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    void operator()(int i) const                { _os << i;              } 
    void operator()(std::string const &s) const { _os << std::quoted(s); } 

    template <typename... Ts> void operator()(std::vector<Ts...> const& v) const {
        _os << "[ ";
        bool first = true;
        for (auto& el : v) {
            if (first) first = false;
            else       _os << ", ";
            call(el);
        }
        _os << " ]";
    }
};

int main() {
    ObjectE obj = ObjectV { 
        1,
        "hello world",
        ObjectV {
            42, ObjectV { "some more" }, -42
        },
    };

    printer print{std::cout};
    print(obj);
}
```

Printing

```
[ 1, "hello world", [ 42, [ "some more" ], -42 ] ]
```

### Even More: Pretty Indenting

Now that we've lost the baggage of the string, we can add some state to the visitor again. Let's make it pretty print with indentation.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f96298f0f9c74ac)</kbd>**

```
struct printer {
    using result_type = void;
    std::ostream& _os;
    std::string _indent = "";

    template <typename... Ts> void operator()(boost::variant<Ts...> const& v) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    void operator()(int i) const                { _os << i;              } 
    void operator()(std::string const &s) const { _os << std::quoted(s); } 

    template <typename... Ts> void operator()(std::vector<Ts...> const& v) const {
        _os << "[";
        auto indent = _indent + "    ";

        bool first = true;
        for (auto& el : v) {
            if (first) first = false;
            else _os << ",";
            _os << "\n" << indent;
            printer{_os, indent}(el);
        }

        if (!v.empty())
            _os << "\n" << _indent;
        _os << "]";
    }
};
```

Prints

```
[
    1,
    "hello world",
    [],
    [
        42,
        [
            "some more"
        ],
        -42
    ]
]
```

### For The Win: Without Recursive Variant, Neat Literals

I noticed you wrote your pseudo-code more like JSON:

```
ObjectE t = ["string" , [1, 2] , ["str2", "str3"], [1,3,6], [[1,2], [1,4]]]
```

That's not C++. However, I can make it work like this:

```
ObjectE t = {"string" , {1, 2} , {"str2", "str3"}, {1,3,6}, {{1,2}, {1,4}}};
```

You do so by making a type derived from variant, and adding a constructor that takes an initializer list for the vector element:

```
struct ObjectE : boost::variant<std::string, int, std::vector<ObjectE> > {
    using Base = boost::variant<std::string, int, std::vector<ObjectE> >;

    using Base::variant;
    using Base::operator=;

    ObjectE(std::initializer_list<ObjectE> init) : Base(std::vector<ObjectE>(init)) {}
};
```

That's all. The improved visitor above was generic *enough* from the start, so we don't need to change another line of code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/639af8ee107f6b25)</kbd>**

```
printer print{std::cout};
print(ObjectE { 1, "hello world", {}, { 42, { "some more" }, -42 } });

std::cout << "\nt: ";

ObjectE t = {"string" , {1, 2} , {"str2", "str3"}, {1,3,6}, {{1,2}, {1,4}}};
print(t);
```

Prints

```
[
    1,
    "hello world",
    [],
    [
        42,
        [
            "some more"
        ],
        -42
    ]
]
t: [
    "string",
    [
        1,
        2
    ],
    [
        "str2",
        "str3"
    ],
    [
        1,
        3,
        6
    ],
    [
        [
            1,
            2
        ],
        [
            1,
            4
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I.. wasn't expecting such in depth answer. Will be reviewing them and applying what i learn from this with a another session. I was trying to use ostream before. Kept running into issues. Now I understand why. Thank for that tidbit.

Comment: For the win, I added the final step that takes you to `print(ObjectE {"string" , {1, 2} , {"str2", "str3"}, {1,3,6}, {{1,2}, {1,4}}});` as your dream code had it :) **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/639af8ee107f6b25)**

Comment: @Leruce "I.. wasn't expecting such in depth answer." We call that the sehe effect.

Comment: Hi Coliru,
I am getting below error when putting elements of different type.
My C++ version is bit old.

Comment: @ChandanKSingh I asked the God of Coliru, but he doesn't know what you mean either. Did you forget to include a coliru link?